# Does the OS interact with assembly code?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

It has to stop processes some times to switch between other ones and it also has to monitor operations like memory access. So does OS just check and run instructions one by one?

Ps. I have just started learning assembly language and computer architecture :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of hardware provides for timed interrupts which will fire every so often somewhat independent of software.  Raised interrupts correspond to memory locations which contain procedures that will be executed when that interrupt is raised, in this case the procedures perform what is known as context switching and process scheduling.  Most of the hardware information such as the program counter and various register contents will are stored in each process's information structure.  The contents of the machine's registers (that the program was using) are restored before the program begins executing again.  Picking up a book on Operating system design will go into much more detail on how all of this is accomplished.

Comment: Thank you! So CPU has much more abilities than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

The OS doesn't execute code, the processor does.  Protected mode is also implemented by the processor, the OS only configures it.  The trap that's triggered by a violation is handled by OS code, eventually causing the process to be terminated if it cannot be handled in a reasonable way.  A context switch is started by a hardware interrupt from a clock tick.  Or a blocking I/O system call.

Answer (score 0):

No, the OS does not check instructions as it would be prohibitively complex and expensive (slow) to do that in the OS. The CPU does memory access checks and when they fail it executes designated code in the OS that, for example, terminates the current process and gives you an error message.